# Nested tqdm progressbar not on same position during run

Tags: python, tqdm

My code consist of a double loop. I want to have a double tqdm progress bar, with the first keeping track of the outer loop, and the second keeping track of the inner loop. They should keep their position; only the inner loop progress bar should be cleared and start at zero at every outer iteration. The code I have now looks like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

outer_loop = 2
inner_loop = 3

pbar_outer = tqdm(total=outer_loop, position=0, leave=True, ncols=80, ascii=True)

for n in range(outer_loop):
    pbar_outer.set_description(f"outer iteration {n + 1}")
    pbar_outer.update()
    sleep(1)

    pbar_inner = tqdm(total=inner_loop, position=1, leave=False, ncols=80, ascii=True)
    for m in range(inner_loop):
        pbar_inner.set_description(f"inner iteration {m + 1}")
        pbar_inner.update()
        sleep(1)

    pbar_inner.close()

pbar_outer.close()
```

Although this works, the problem is that the inner loop progress bar keeps be written to a new line during each iteration. The output looks like this:

```
outer iteration 1:   0%|                                  | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|                                                     | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
inner iteration 1:   0%|                                  | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
inner iteration 2:  33%|########6                 | 1/3 [00:01<00:02,  1.00s/it]
inner iteration 2:  67%|#################3        | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]
inner iteration 3:  67%|#################3        | 2/3 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
inner iteration 3: 100%|##########################| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.41it/s]
outer iteration 2: 100%|##########################| 2/2 [00:04<00:00,  2.00s/it]
  0%|                                                     | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
inner iteration 1:   0%|                                  | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
inner iteration 2:  33%|########6                 | 1/3 [00:01<00:02,  1.00s/it]
inner iteration 2:  67%|#################3        | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]
inner iteration 3:  67%|#################3        | 2/3 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
inner iteration 3: 100%|##########################| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.41it/s]
outer iteration 2: 100%|##########################| 2/2 [00:08<00:00,  4.01s/it]
```

As you can, there are several problems. Most notably is that the second progress bar is not kept on the same position, but written to a new line. In case I use `position=0`  for the second progress bar, the position is kept fixed, but then the second bar is plotted right on top of the first bar. Other problems are that the progress bar is initiated with an empty message (the default), and then plotted again with the first message. Also, the third inner iteration is plotted twice: one time with 67%, and then with 100%.

Hopefully anybody has some advice on having 2 nested progress bars using the tqdm module which are kept on a fixed position.

Comment: Run your script in the system command line environment ( terminal ) to see that the progress bar stays at its position. Which enviroment are you using? I am getting similar behavior as you describe in the terminal panel of SciTE, but not in a system terminal window.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solves the problem, I am running in PyCharm, but running in a terminal indeed solves the problem! I only have to remove the close of the second progress bar, otherwise it gets removed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Claudio I have solved it. I was running in PyCharm, whereas running in a terminal doesn't show this behavior.

You only should not close the second progress bar, and also to fix the initialization of the second bar it is better to do that outside of the loops.

Another cause of getting new lines is when your line becomes too wide. I found that for `ncols=120`, I was still getting new lines. So reducing `ncols` to 80 helps as well (depending on your terminal I guess)

For a reference, I am posting my updated script:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

outer_loop = 2
inner_loop = 3

pbar_outer = tqdm(total=outer_loop, position=0, leave=True, ncols=80, ascii=True)
pbar_inner = tqdm(total=inner_loop, position=1, leave=False, ncols=80, ascii=True)

for n in range(outer_loop):
    pbar_outer.set_description(f"outer iteration {n + 1}")
    pbar_outer.update()
    sleep(1)

    for m in range(inner_loop):
        pbar_inner.set_description(f"inner iteration {m + 1}")
        pbar_inner.update()
        sleep(1)

pbar_outer.close()
```

The output now looks like:

```
outer iteration 2: 100%|##########################| 2/2 [00:08<00:00,  4.01s/it]
inner iteration 3: 100%|##########################| 3/3 [00:02<00:00,  1.41it/s]
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any idea how to fix it in PyCharm?

Comment: Doesn´t work in pycharm for me, I run my scripts in a separate shell (bash or powershell) and then it looks fine

Comment: I found it.
Run > Edit Configurations > Emulate terminal in output console